# SetAttribute on a specific position in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following `iframe`

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/adLvq2haaFg" class="note-video-clip"></iframe>
```

When I target `iframe` through `getElementsByTagName` like this

```js
let a = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
a.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '');
```

It returns:

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/adLvq2haaFg" class="note-video-clip" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

It's creating a problem for me because it is not working as expected. When I manually insert `allowfullscreen` at beginning it's working well.

This is the result I want instead

```html
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/adLvq2haaFg" class="note-video-clip" ></iframe>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about `setAttribute("allowFullScreen", true);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to add `allowfullscreen=""` just after the tag name is to modify the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) of the element using string method [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and array method [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) as in the code below.

```js
const miFrame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
console.log(miFrame);

// Split the outerHTML string into separate pieces
// by using a space as the separator
const miFrameOH = miFrame.outerHTML.split(' ');

// Using splice(position, deleteCount, itemToAdd),
// add attribute at index 1
miFrameOH.splice(1, 0, 'allowfullscreen=""');

// Join the parts (including the attribute) with a space separator and
// set this string to the outerHTML
miFrame.outerHTML = miFrameOH.join(' ');
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/adLvq2haaFg" class="note-video-clip"></iframe>
```